# Do I need buffer amps and zeners for SPI pins in a tiny IC chip?

Tags: arduino, circuit-analysis, spi, microchip

I am currently working on a project using the MMA9555L pedometer chip (from Freescale Semiconductor Inc.) and establishing communications through an SPI bus going into an Arduino Uno. Below is a picture of the circuit I intend to use initially which is from the data sheet of the chip.

[image]

Before I power it up I am not sure about one thing. Arduino pins outputs 5V for digital signals however all the IO and SPI pins in this chip works at 1.8V. Will I need Zener diodes or voltage regulators as well as an Opamp in buffer amp configuration (to make sure current is limited) for each of the data pins? For reference, I will be doing the initial testing on a breadboard so no fancy (small form factor) components initially.

Sorry if my question sounds silly, I am only a mechanical engineer and do not have much experience with IC circuitry.

Comment: Voltage dividers and transistors is fine indeed as long as you know what you're doing. As long as you pay attention to the direction of the signals and polarity (a transistor circuit often inverts the signal) it should work fine. The advantage of a chip is that they're convenient.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Opamps/zeners: no that is too complicated, what you need are **levelshifters**.

That can be in the form of a chip, some resistors (for 5 V to 1.8 V) or a transistor and a resistor (1.8 V to 5 V). You can also buy small ready-made levelshifter boards on eBay. [An example](http://www.ebay.nl/itm/1-2V-1-8V-2-5V-3-3V-5V-8-Kanal-Logic-Level-Converter-Fur-Arduino-/121977377834?hash=item1c666b142a:g:VF4AAOSwaB5XutDm).

[or this one](https://www.adafruit.com/product/757) from Adafruit[2](https://www.adafruit.com/product/757)

[image: another one]